# Keep bigger size image file and delete image files with smaller sizes of same name, using terminal command

Tags: delete, rm

Keep bigger size image file and delete image files with smaller sizes of same name, using terminal command

My directory may contain a_500.jpg, a_1280.jpg BUT b_500.jpg, c_500.jpg, c_800.jpg.

So, in that case b_500.jpg is a unique image file (the biggest one).

So, i want to find all the biggest file of the same series based on "xxxxx" in xxxx_resolution.jpg, and delete the rest ones using terminal command.

How i can do that?

Comment: Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: When folks are learning, I suggest breaking the problem into smaller pieces: "How to X?", "How to take the result of X and apply action Y?", "How to take the result of Y and apply action Z?" If somebody here gives you a long, complex, magical incantation that you don't quite understand and cannot maintain, then how can you be sure that it's really doing what you want?

Comment: I have seen more complex answers and questions from mine. I am using linux many years now and i have made myself complex commands for doing things. :)

Comment: @wailtinator problem stated, expected result stated clearly. If you like to add some more info, tell me what exactly. I have downloaded a tumblr blogpost, and has multiple size images. I want to keep the bigger ones. It is not stated so clearly?